# How does - represent compressed data?

Tags: data, compression

The Wolfram Blog article "The Semantic Representation of Pure Mathematics", by Eric Weisstein and Ian Ford (http://blog.wolfram.com/2016/12/22/the-semantic-representation-of-pure-mathematics/) has a Comment by the first author that links to a notebook `TopologyEntityStore.nb` (https://exploration.open.wolframcloud.com/objects/exploration/TopologyEntityStore.nb).

The first Input cell of that notebook appears like this:

```
imstore = -;
```

but if you examine the expression in that cell as text, you see:

```
Cell[BoxData[
  RowBox[{
    RowBox[{"imstore", "-",
    GraphicsBox[
      TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData[" ...
....
```

(many, many lines after that not shown here).

Question: What does that `-` mean? And how does the expression `imstore = -` work?

I found no entry `CompressedData` in the Documentation Center.

Comment: I think `CompressedData` is just a front-end way of specifying that an expression should be auto `Uncompress`-ed when needed. It clearly also behaves in special ways with boxes (compare `With[{data = Compress@ArrayReshape[RandomInteger[256, 10000], {100, 100}]}, RawBoxes@RasterBox[CompressedData@data]]` with its `Uncompress` twin. But if you use it as a function there seems to be no difference.

Answer (score 9):

The - is not a character but actually an Image. It is a very clever trick that was used. Each pixel in the image represents an ascii character after a transformation.

Let's review how this image was assembled by an example.

```
graph = HoldForm[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotLabel -> "Sample Graph"]];
chars = ToCharacterCode[ToString@graph]
(*{80, 108, 111, 116, 91, 83, 105, 110, 91, 120, 93, 44, 32, 123, 120, \
44, 32, 48, 44, 32, 50, 32, 80, 105, 125, 44, 32, 80, 108, 111, 116, \
76, 97, 98, 101, 108, 32, 45, 62, 32, 83, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 32, \
71, 114, 97, 112, 104, 93}*)
len = Length[chars];
img = Image[
  Partition[Join[chars, ConstantArray[0, 64 - len]]/65535., 8]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now back to an expression

```
ToExpression[
 FromCharacterCode[
  Take[Flatten[Round[ImageData[img] 65535, 1]], len]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Why the `64-len` there?  Exactly what is going on?